# Generating Random String of Numbers and Letters Using Go's "testing/quick" Package

Tags: testing, go, unicode, generator, unicode-normalization

I've been breaking my head over this for a few days now and can't seem to be able to figure it out. Perhaps it's glaringly obvious, but I don't seem to be able to spot it. I've read up on all the basics of unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16, normalisation, etc, but to no avail. Hopefully somebody's able to help me out here...

I'm using Go's `Value` function from the [`testing/quick`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/quick/) package to generate random values for the fields in my data structs, in order to implement the [`Generator` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/quick/#Generator) for the structs in question. Specifically, given a `Metadata` struct, I've defined the implementation as follows:

```
func (m *Metadata) Generate(r *rand.Rand, size int) (value reflect.Value) {
    value = reflect.ValueOf(m).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < value.NumField(); i++ {
        if t, ok := quick.Value(value.Field(i).Type(), r); ok {
            value.Field(i).Set(t)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Now, in doing so, I'll end up with both the receiver and the return value being set with random generated values of the appropriate type (strings, ints, etc. in the receiver and reflect.Value in the returned reflect.Value).

Now, the implementation for the `Value` function states that it will return something of type `[]rune` converted to type `string`. As far as I know, this should allow me to then use the functions in the `runes`, `unicode` and `norm` packages to define a filter which filters out everything which is not part of *'Latin'*, *'Letter'* or *'Number'*. I defined the following filter which uses a transform to filter out letters which are not in those character `rangetable`s (as defined in the `unicode` package):

```
func runefilter(in reflect.Value) (out reflect.Value) {
    out = in // Make sure you return something
    if in.Kind() == reflect.String {
        instr := in.String()
        t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, runes.Remove(runes.NotIn(rangetable.Merge(unicode.Letter, unicode.Latin, unicode.Number))), norm.NFC)
        outstr, _, _ := transform.String(t, instr)
        out = reflect.ValueOf(outstr)
    }
    return
}
```

Now, I think I've tried just about anything, but I keep ending up with a series of strings which are far from the Latin range, e.g.:

```
똿穊

嚶
秓䝏小䮋
ท솲
䂾

ʋᦸ
堮憨ꥆ
併怃
鯮

⓿ꐠ槹黟
踁퓺
俇


쩈詢


欓
```

So, can anybody explain what I'm overlooking here and how I could instead define a `transformer` which removes/replaces non-letter/number/latin characters so that I can use the `Value` function as intended (but with a smaller subset of 'random' characters)?

Thanks!

Comment: You're starting with random unicode codepoints, but trying to filter only latin characters which are a very small subset, so even if you get this method working you will only get empty strings most of the time.

Comment: Yes, I already realised that. I still don't end up with empty strings after filtering however. I'm mainly concerned with why it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: [`Merge returns a new RangeTable that is the union of the given tables`](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/unicode/rangetable/merge.go#L14-L21) - so you're probably getting any (latin || letter || number) -- which is a large number of possible characters.

Comment: Aha! Yes, of course! It's not the intersection! Thanks so much for pointing that out... Will update the post asap (also pointing out the small subset remark from JimB earlier)

Comment: Have u looked into using [Go Fuzz](https://github.com/dvyukov/go-fuzz) for randomized input testing?

Comment: No, not yet @eduncan911 and it's actually next on my list of things to go into regarding testing in Go.

I 'discovered' the somewhat overlooked (IMO) `testing/quick` package recently and looking for some more information on its rationale and idiomatic use, I came across [this](http://blog.matttproud.com/2015/06/testingquick-blackbox-testing-in-go-for.html) post, which goes into it. For now, I'm trying to figure out the `quick` package and why nobody seems to use it, as it appears to be quite powerful in all its simplicity. But perhaps that's just my lack of insight.
In any case, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusingly the Generate interface needs a function using the type not a the pointer to the type. You want your type signature to look like

`func (m Metadata) Generate(r *rand.Rand, size int) (value reflect.Value)`

You can play with this [here](https://play.golang.org/p/w23Gd2_GGc). Note: the most important thing to do in that playground is to switch the type of the generate function from `m Metadata` to `m *Metadata` and see that Hi Mom! never prints.

In addition, I think you would be better served using your own type and writing a generate method for that type using a list of all of the characters you want to use. For example:

```
type LatinString string
const latin = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01233456789"
```

and then use the generator

```
func (l LatinString) Generate(rand *rand.Rand, size int) reflect.Value {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        buffer.WriteString(string(latin[rand.Intn(len(latin))]))
    }
    s := LatinString(buffer.String())
    return reflect.ValueOf(s)
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/daAwu6t9oj)

Edit: also this library is pretty cool, thanks for showing it to me

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the pointer part. Your suggestion is indeed the logical workaround. Thing is, that something like this is just what I kept on doing over and over again in order to generate test data. This meant having to redefine the function for generating random strings everywhere I wanted those and write pretty contrived code to get it all working. Basically, a lot of extra code, repeated everywhere I needed it, which it turns out I could easily replace with a standard package.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question is, it seems, a combination of the answers provided in the comments by @nj_ and @jimb and the answer provided by @benjaminkadish.

In short, the answer boils down to:

1. "*Not such a great idea as you thought it was*", or "*Bit of an ill-posed question*"
2. "You were using the *union* of *'Letter'*, *'Latin'* and *'Number'* (`Letter || Number || Latin`), instead of the *intersection* of *'Latin'* with the *union* of *'Letter'* and *'Number'* (`(Letter || Number) && Latin)`)

Now for the longer version...

The idea behind me using the `testing/quick` package is that I wanted random data for (fuzzy) testing of my code. In the past, I've always written the code for doing things like that myself, again and again. This meant a lot of the same code across different projects. Now, I could of course written my own package for it, but it turns out that, even better than that, there's actually a standard package which does just about exactly what I want.

Now, it turns out the package does exactly what I want very well. The *codepoints* in the strings which it generates are actually *random* and not just restricted to what we're accustomed to using in everyday life. Now, this is of course exactly the thing which you want in doing fuzzy testing in order to test the code with values outside the usual assumptions.

In practice, that means I'm running into two problems:

1. There's some limits on what I would consider *reasonable* input for a string. Meaning that, in testing the processing of a `Name` field or a `URL` field, I can *reasonably* assume there's not going to be a value like 'James Mc⌢' (let alone 'James Mc') or 'www.site.com', but just 'James McFrown' and 'www.website.com'. Hence, I can't expect a *reasonable* system to be able to support it. Of course, things shouldn't completely break down, but it also can't be expected to handle the former examples without any problems.
2. When I filter the generated string on values which one might consider *reasonable*, the chance of ending up with a valid string is very small. The set of possible characters in the set used by the `testing/quick` is just so large (0x10FFFF) and the set of *reasonable* characters so small, you end up with empty strings most of the time.

So, what do we need to take away from this?

So, whilst I hoped to use the standard `testing/quick` package to replace my often repeated code to generate random data for fuzzy testing, it does this so well that it provides data outside the range of what I would consider reasonable for the code to be able to handle. It seems that the choice, in the end, is to:

1. Either be able to actually handle all fuzzy options, meaning that if somebody's name is 'Arnold ' ('Arnold Moneybags'), it shouldn't go arse over end. Or...
2. Use custom/derived types with their own `Generator`. This means you're going to have to use the derived type instead of the basic type throughout the code. (Comparable to defining a `string` as `wchar_t` instead of `char` in C++ and working with those by default.). Or...
3. Don't use `testing/quick` for fuzzy testing, because as soon as you run into a generated string value, you can (and should) get a very random string.

As always, further comments are of course welcome, as it's quite possible I overlooked something.